# What is the best way to restart NFS service after reboot?

Tags: boot, networking, server, nfs

I export my shares by using host names like:

```
 /export       myubuntupc(rw,...) mywindowspc(ro,...)
```

After boot up `exportfs` fails to resolve host name until I restart `nfs-kernel-server` manually. This is similar to behavior described [here,](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ifupdown/+bug/848823) *see comment 6 and on.*
Sadly the hint at the end does not work for me on 14.04 or 16.04.

I don't know how to do `sudo nfs-kernel-server restart` unattended after boot up. What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

You should append `nfs-kernel-server restart` to the `/etc/rc.local`  or `/etc/rc.d/rc.local`. these files have been used for initial scripts or commands.